# T-SQL for changing data from one table and insert into another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

My base table is like:

```
ColumnA|ColumnB
---------------
   A   |  C1
   A   |  C2
   A   |  C3
   B   |  C1
   B   |  C3
   C   |  C4
```

I want to read records from the base table and write it into the below table:

```
ColumnA | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
----------------------------
   A    | Y  |  Y | Y  | N
   B    | Y  |  N | Y  | N
   C    | N  |  N | N  | Y
```

I don't want to use a cursor, but I don't know if that's possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: something like a pivot table, right?

Comment: yes I think but I don't know how can I use here

Comment: should C->C4 be Y ?
are you trying to build a truth table or just get the displayed output?

Comment: yes it's correct now
I will insert all this data into one new table (i didn't understand what you mean by truth table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (usually fast) way would be `group by`:

```
insert  NewTable (ColumnA, C1, C2, C3, C4)
select  ColumnA
,       IsNull(max(case when ColumnB = 'C1' then 'Y' end), 'N')
,       IsNull(max(case when ColumnB = 'C2' then 'Y' end), 'N')
,       IsNull(max(case when ColumnB = 'C3' then 'Y' end), 'N')
,       IsNull(max(case when ColumnB = 'C4' then 'Y' end), 'N')
from    OldTable
group by
        ColumnA
```

Another way is subqueries, like:

```
insert  NewTable (ColumnA, C1, C2, C3, C4)
select  src.ColumnA
,       case when exists (select * from OldTable ot 
                          where ot.ColumnA = src.ColumnA and ot.ColumnB = 'C1') 
                  then 'Y' else 'N' end
,       case when exists (select * from OldTable ot 
                          where ot.ColumnA = src.ColumnA and ot.ColumnB = 'C2') 
                  then 'Y' else 'N' end
,       case when exists (select * from OldTable ot 
                          where ot.ColumnA = src.ColumnA and ot.ColumnB = 'C3') 
                  then 'Y' else 'N' end
,       case when exists (select * from OldTable ot 
                          where ot.ColumnA = src.ColumnA and ot.ColumnB = 'C4') 
                  then 'Y' else 'N' end
from    (
        select  distinct ColumnA
        from    OldTable
        ) src
```

Or, adapted from Chris Diver's answer, with `pivot`:

```
select  ColumnA
,       case when C1 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end C1
,       case when C2 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end C2
,       case when C3 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end C3
,       case when C4 > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end C4
from    OldTable src
pivot   (
        count(ColumnB)
        for ColumnB IN ([C1], [C2], [C3], [C4])
        ) pvt
```

Comment: +1. This is easier if/when the number of columns to pivot is known at design-time, and is small enough to manage with copy/pasting those subqueries.

Comment: in group by why are you using MAX ?

Comment: @oshin: You have to specify a way for the database to aggregate values from multiple rows.  The expression inside `max()` returns 'Y' for a match and `null` for no match.  The `max()` of that is `Y` if a matching row was found, and `null` otherwise.

Comment: I'm using the group by solution because I compared pivot run time with group by and group by is better .so I'll accept your answer .thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) command. From there you can do a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

```
SELECT ColumnA, [C1], [C2], [C3], [C4]
 FROM (SELECT * FROM table) t 
PIVOT
(
 Count(ColumnB)
 FOR ColumnB IN ([C1], [C2], [C3], [C4])
) As Pvt
```

Comment: As I need just Y or N how can I use a case statement here ?
I'm trying case count(columnB) = 0 then 'N' ELSE 'Y' END but i'm getting error :
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: @oshin: pivot is inflexible in demanding `<aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)`.  Appended a pivot version to my answer that works around that, but please accept Chris Diver's answer if you prefer pivot :)

Comment: You would have to put a case around each of the `[Cx]` in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can SELECT the information you like, then you can write the insert as the result of that selection.